# laravel passport custom password column

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

How can I use Laravel's Passport package to authenticate a different password column.

If i want to authenticate from a different 'username' column, it can be done with the following code:

```
    public function findForPassport($username) {
        return $this->where('id', $username)->first();
    }
```

It will take Id, as the column. What if I want to use a different 'password' column. A column in the table with a different name such as 'uid_token'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a method the Passport/Bridge asks for called `validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)` that you can override in your `user model`, if you don't override this it will look for a `password` column in your user `table`. I'm not entirely sure why they haven't configured it to use `Authenticatable` method getAuthPassword...

Answer (score 11):

Adding this `validateForPassportPasswordGrant` method to User model did the job for me ("PasswMd" - custom column name):

```
public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
{
    return Hash::check($password, $this->PasswMd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the above solutions are great but there is another way to achieve it and it worked for me in Laravel 8.

For future readers I provide the code down here, they need to add to their models and return the custom password column like so.

```
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->PasswMd;
    }
```