# Laravel Passport: Use custom password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I want to use `user_password` instead of just `password` for the name of the password column for the database of my API. So here is the code of the `login()` method to retrieve the token in my `PassportController`:

```
public function login() {
    if (Auth::attempt(['user_login' => request('login'), 'password' => request('user_password')])) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('ToutelaBreizh')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised.'], 401);
    }
}
```

The parameters of the request to this controller are `login` and `password`.

The problem is when I go to the route associated to this controller, let's say `POST /api/login`. I get this error:

> ErrorException: Undefined index: password in file ... EloquentUserProvider.php on line 133
>
> [First lines of the stack trace...]
>
> 7. ... PassportController.php:21

The 21st line in my PassportController is the second line of the login function I posted above and indeed, the `password` field is not informed in the credentials I wrote: I wrote `user_password` instead of `password`, but the string `password` is hard coded in the EloquentUserProvider.php, line 133:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606818/laravel-passport-custom-password-column), I tried to override the `validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)` in the `User.php` model but it didn't help:

```
public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
{
    return Hash::check($password, $this->user_password);
}
```

How should I do to have `user_password` in my database and not `password`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That issue is actually not specific to Passport, it has more to do with the Auth Guard behavior, which is abstracted from Passport.  Simply add this to your user Model:

```
/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->user_password;
}
```

Laravel's out-of-the-box `App\User` Model extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`, which uses the `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait.  That trait is just a convenience for satisfying the conditions of the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface, one of which is to have basically a getter for whatever your password field is named.  You'd be overriding this.

The word 'password' in the context of grant-types is an entirely different thing by the way, and not something you should have to change like that.  That has more to do with a configuration reference, and not a database field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, it has returned me the same error: `Undefined index: password`.