# Use Different Tables For Login Laravel Passport Api

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-passport

I'm new on laravel passport api! i need a little help, i'm creating a login api where rider(user) wants to logged in using Contact Number and Password, but problem is that contact number is in different table name profile or password is in different table called Rider, Is it possible to use two different table in passport api? 
I'm using this method

```
public function findForPassport($username) {

        return Profile::where('contact_number', $username)->first();
    }
```

but problem is that when i used this, in postman there is error getAuthPassword does not exist, can anyone tell me how i implement two tables in laravel passport api?
i'm using this function to get password

```
 public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return Rider::where('password', $this->password)->first();
    }
```

i need help please...

Comment: anyone here to help please?

Comment: I am not familiar with Laravel Passport but I can help by recommending you to also ask on Laravel Slack workspace: https://larachat.co/slack. Also, your question looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606818/laravel-passport-custom-password-column

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin i used this but did not help, then i asked question

Comment: You will never, and should never, be able to query a user based on their password in Laravel. Passwords are salted with a random salt and hashed, so your second query will never work, and nor should it as this would be a terrible security risk.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it with Passport directly. there is a user_id field in the passport tables. Passport's implementation assumes one user model, and there is no documentation on how to user several user models.

Comment: This is one attempt to go around that: https://github.com/jsdecena/laravel-passport-mutiauth